# IndexError: tuple index out of range(XGBoost)

Tags: python, xgboost, index-error

I am trying to predict weekly sales of a bunch of stores. I want to use `XGBoost` but I keep running into this error:

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

My code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

features = ["Store",'Dept','Temperature','Fuel_Price','CPI','Unemployment']

y = allmergecopy.Weekly_Sales
X = allmergecopy[features]
X_train, y_train, X_valid, y_valid = train_test_split(y,X,test_size=.2, train_size=.8)

from xgboost import XGBRegressor

my_model = XGBRegressor(n_estimators=100)
my_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

For reference:

`y_train.shape = (84314,), X_train.shape = (337256,)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use X as:

`X=allmergecopy.drop("Weekly_Sales",axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

instead of :

```
X_train, y_train, X_valid, y_valid = train_test_split(y,X,test_size=.2, train_size=.8)
```

write :

```
x_train,x_valid,y_train,y_valid= train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2)
```

and then use :

```
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
my_model = XGBRegressor(n_estimators=100)
my_model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```